# Como puedo cambiar el Idle Connection Timeout de un Websocket en AWS Services?

Tags: api, aws, websocket, connection

Estoy usando la conexión websocket de API Gateway y he leído estos límites: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html, en la seccion de **API Gateway quotas for configuring and running a WebSocket API**.

En esta doc dice que Idle Connection Timeout dura 10 minutos.

La pregunta es hay alguna manera de minimizar este tiempo, por me dio de una petición o configuración de websockets de AWS.?